# Why doesn't my recently run task show up in the Task Status window

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

Using the Windows 7 Task Scheduler, I created a very simple task (a .cmd file to delete a file) and set it to run a couple of minutes in the future.

The task ran (the target file has been deleted), but it never shows up in the Task Status window of Task Scheduler. The period "Last 24 hours" is selected, and I've hit Refresh, but the status window shows 0 tasks total (and 0 running, succeeded, stopped, failed).

It's a one-time trigger and the task is not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Your task history is probably disabled -- on the right side of the Task Scheduler window, under "Actions", click on the item "Enable All Tasks History"